# stuck,completeness,repeatedly to list all files in directory with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, list, traversal

I want to list all files in specified directory with nodejs.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var walk = function(directoryName) {
  fs.readdir(directoryName, function(e, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      fs.stat(directoryName + path.sep + file, function(e, f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
          walk(directoryName + path.sep + file)
        } else {
          console.log('-' + file)
        }
      })
    })
  })
}

walk("/home")
```

Three confued problem for the result.

1.stuck
To execute the above nodejs in node console in serveral minutes,the cursor stop there ,no node promt chracter `>` display ,just a static cursor.
Does the static cursor mean nodejs program stuck?

2.completeness
Is true or false that all files listed ,none of them left before cursor stop there?

3.repeatedly
In the attachment, many same file names listed such as `BasicLatin.js` and `CombDiacritMarks.js`,same files listed repeatedly?

[image]

To fix the statement `console.log('-' + file)` into `console.log(directoryName + path.sep + file)` and save as list.js and run with command `node list.js`,issue 2 and issue 3 solved.
All files listed and no same file repeatedly.

To input `node` in terminal and run the program line by line.
Why no node prompt character `>` display after listing all files when to run in node console?
It seems program stuck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: this isn't a complete answer yet. Need further information but
>   comments are too short. I will edit/delete my answer depending on your
>   response.

I ran your code on my Ubuntu machine and it completed with exit code 0. I had to handle the error on the callback to allow it to run to completion but it didn't get stuck.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var walk = function(directoryName) {
  fs.readdir(directoryName, function(e, files) {
    if (!e) {
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        fs.stat(directoryName + path.sep + file, function (e, f) {
          if (!e) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
              walk(directoryName + path.sep + file)
            } else {
              console.log(' - ' + file)
            }
          } else {
            console.log(e);
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })
}

walk("/home")
```

So it doesn't seem there is something totally incorrect with your code.

Regarding your questions

1. How are you executing your code?
2. Please run a test on a smaller directory hierarchy than /home. I assume this is /home on a unix/linux machine.
3. Same as above. Let's take BasicLatin.js. Run the program displaying the full path and check if they are truly duplicates.